# Multiplos Joins com Active record retornando nulo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Amigos, tenho as seguintes saidas do console (Rails 4.1):

```
Product.all
    Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 4, cod: "160", descricao: "Sutiã", price: #<BigDecimal:103c2d810,'0.1E2',9(27)>, created_at: "2016-05-18 17:05:35", updated_at: "2016-05-18 17:05:35">]>

Size.all


Size Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "sizes".* FROM "sizes"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Size id: 1, descricao: "P", created_at: "2016-03-09 23:23:49", updated_at: "2016-03-09 23:23:49">, #<Size id: 2, descricao: "M", created_at: "2016-03-09 23:23:56", updated_at: "2016-03-09 23:23:56">, #<Size id: 3, descricao: "G", created_at: "2016-03-09 23:24:00", updated_at: "2016-03-09 23:24:00">]>



Variation.all
  Variation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "variations".* FROM "variations"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Variation id: 35, product_id: "4", size_id: "1", color_id: "1", quantity: 4, barcode: "160P1000001000", created_at: "2016-05-18 17:05:35", updated_at: "2016-06-01 18:45:19">, #<Variation id: 36, product_id: "4", size_id: "2", color_id: "2", quantity: 10, barcode: "160M1100001000", created_at: "2016-05-18 17:05:35", updated_at: "2016-06-01 17:15:24">]>
```

E quando executo este comando:

```
Variation.joins(:product,:size,:color).select('products.cod as cod_produto,products.descricao as desc_produto,colors.descricao as desc_cor,sizes.descricao as desc_tamanho,products.price as preco,variations.quantity as quantidade,variations.barcode as cod_barras')
```

Recebo esta resposta:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Variation id: nil>, #<Variation id: nil>]>
```

**O que está errado ? Se eu executar a query direto ele retorna mas eu preciso que seja feito com o active record pois preciso gerar um csv disso.**

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não faz um escopo?

```
scope :variation_csv, -> (product_id, size_id, color_id) { where product_id: product_id, size_id: size_id, color_id: color_id) }
```

Comment: Teria como me ajudar com um exemplo de como usaria isso?

Comment: Já tentou o escopo? Coloca esse exemplo que postei no model e chama ele no console `Variation.first.variation_csv` e vê se resolve a questão das associações. Para exportar em csv vc criaria um método no model passando o objeto com as associações `self.variation_csv`

Comment: Sim mas eu preciso na verdade é pegar os campos das tabelas associadas tb, não só os campoa de variarions. Neste seu exemplo como faria pra pegar os demais campos?

Comment: Não funcionou. Da o seguinte erro: Variation.first.variation_csv
  Variation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "variations".* FROM "variations"   ORDER BY "variations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `variation_csv' for #<Variation:0x00000103d8e678>. Coloquei no variation.rb, tinha um erro no seu codigo coloquei assim: scope :variation_csv, -> (product_id, size_id, color_id) { (where product_id: product_id, size_id: size_id, color_id: color_id) }